# i am confused what to put after paste function ,and also after write.csv

Tags: shiny

issue that needed to be resolved
#for ui part,
actionButton( "Enter","SUBMIT",class = "btn-primary btn-lg
active"),tags$hr(),verbatimTextOutput("depdelay"),downloadButton("downloaddata","Down load file")

```
#for server side
 output$downloaddata<-downloadHandler(
    filename = function(){
      paste("output$depdelay","csv")  
    },
    content = function(file){
        write.csv(ypred47(),file)
    }
)
```

Comment: i am confused what should i put after paste(),

Comment: and after write.csv()

Comment: I'm cionfused about what you are asking.  Please provide a minimum reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.  But... The body of your `filename()` function should probably be `paste0(output$depdelay, ".csv")`.  Your `content()` function could be OK, but without a MWE it's impossible to be sure.  Have you looked at [this page](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/0.14/downloadHandler.html)?  Welcome to SO.

Answer (score 0):

You only need `paste` if you want a custom filename when the user downloads. See example below

```
output$downloadDat <- downloadHandler(
  filename = function(){paste("Data Download at ",Sys.time(), ".csv", sep = "")},
  content = function(file){write.csv(df, file)}
)
```

Otherwise, you can remove the `paste` function entirely.

```
output$downloadDat <- downloadHandler(
  filename = function(){"Data Download.csv"},
  content = function(file){write.csv(df, file)}
)
```

Reference: https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/0.14/downloadHandler.html

You were missing the "." for the file extension in your paste function. You could do `paste("output$depdelay","csv", sep = ".")`

Comment: i don't know how to format the question,but you understood it completely,and provided a better solution.@kevin